# Remove "A" in front of Appendix in TOC

Tags: appendices

I want to remove "A" in front of "Appendix" that appears in my TOC. Does anyone know how to do so? I am using commands

```
\appendix   
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
\chapter{Appendix}
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are several possible approaches.  \let\thechapter=\empty is one.  Remove \appendix and use \chapter*{Appendix} is probably better, depending on what you want in the table of contents.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I use Appendix to list some theorems and now these theorems are listed as Theorem A.1, Theorem A.2 , etc. If I use the code \chapter*{Appendix}, these numberings will disappear. Is there any way I can remove "A" in front of Appendix in the TOC and still maintain the numbing in Appendix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you invoque `\appendix` the format of the chapter changes to `Alph{Chapter}`, to avoid that change you can redefine `\thechapter` format:

```
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}} % Force the format to Roman or another you want..
```

This change is included in the TOC